# Menus of LibreOffice cannot be handled with KDE appmenu in Kubuntu 13.04

Tags: kubuntu, kde, libreoffice, appmenu

After installing Kubuntu 13.04, LibreOffice 4.0.2.2 worked, but the menus looked without borders and flat, and if I tried to use appmenu (or appmenu button) the applications were not affected (the ugly menus stayed at the windows). I removed libreoffice-kde and installed libreoffice-gtk, which took care of the menus and now they look quite similar as any other kde app, and, as far as I know, lo-menubar is now part of this package.

However, if I try to use another style for the menu (either "Title bar button" or "Top screen menubar") Writer, for instance, ends up without any menu at all. I checked and I have installed appmenu-gtk, appmenu-gtk3, appmenu-qt. Should I need to install anything else, or modify any configuration file?

Answer (score 3):

Remove `libreoffice-gtk` and install `libreoffice-kde` and `libreoffice-style-oxygen`.